# saving VLC player snapshot with filename same as video filename

Tags: vlc

How can I save a snapshot from VLC player with a filename exactly the same as the video file playing. i.e. playing video file `examplevideo52.mp4`  I want to be able to save a snapshot with the filename `examplevideo52.jpg`

Comment: why do you need to play it with vlc? you can split it to frames with ffmpeg

Comment: I want to save an image of a certain frame.

Comment: which OS .... ?

Comment: Windows 10 x64.

Answer (score 8):

With the existing settings, the closest you can get for a video file named `sample.mp4` is a snapshot with name `sample.mp4-0001.jpg`.

You can achieve this using following settings. Settings -> Video -> Video Snapshots 
[image]

You can find more tags at - https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Play_HowTo/Format_String/

Comment: _$N : name (media name as seen in the VLC playlist)_

If a name is set in the metadata, VLC will use that instead of file name.